# Union multiple result from select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL block code.

```
use TestDatabase

declare @keyword nvarchar(1000) = '';
declare @sqlKeyword nvarchar(1000) = '';

set @sqlKeyword =
    'select * into #tmphosovanban from TblHoSoVB
            select *  from(
                select * from (
                --tim tu khoa theo district
                        ( select * from  #tmphosovanban
                            where  DCHCHuyenID in (select DistrictID from MstDistrict where DistrictName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'' )
                            or DatHCHuyenID in (select DistrictID from MstDistrict where DistrictName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'' )
                             )
                        union

                --tim tu khoa theo town
                        (select * from  #tmphosovanban
                            where DCHCXaID in (select TownID from MstTown where TownName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                            or DatHCXaID in (select TownID from MstTown where TownName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                            )
                        union
                --tim tu khoa theo nguon goc dat
                        (select * from  #tmphosovanban
                            where NGSuDungDatID in (select MasterID from MstCommonMaster where MasterName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                            or MDSuDungDatID in (select MasterID from MstCommonMaster where MasterName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                            or LoaiTaiSanID in (select MasterID from MstCommonMaster where MasterName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                            )
                        union 
                        (select * from  #tmphosovanban
                            where ViTriLuuID in (select GiaID from MstViTriGia where TenGia like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                        )

                ) as temp
        ) as temp2 
        drop table #tmphosovanban'
exec(@sqlKeyword)
```

I get an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

when I run this block on SQL Server. I don't know why it is wrong. It runs when I delete one of the following blocks, so I think my syntax is right and it doesn't run because another reason. How can I fix this?

```
        --tim tu khoa theo district
                ( select * from  #tmphosovanban
                    where  DCHCHuyenID in (select DistrictID from MstDistrict where DistrictName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'' )
                    or DatHCHuyenID in (select DistrictID from MstDistrict where DistrictName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'' )
                     )
                union


        --tim tu khoa theo town
                (select * from  #tmphosovanban
                    where DCHCXaID in (select TownID from MstTown where TownName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                    or DatHCXaID in (select TownID from MstTown where TownName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                    )
                union

        --tim tu khoa theo nguon goc dat
                (select * from  #tmphosovanban
                    where NGSuDungDatID in (select MasterID from MstCommonMaster where MasterName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                    or MDSuDungDatID in (select MasterID from MstCommonMaster where MasterName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                    or LoaiTaiSanID in (select MasterID from MstCommonMaster where MasterName like N''%'+@keyword+'%'')
                    )
                union
```

Comment: Your variable `@sqlKeyword nvarchar(1000)` is lesser then the amount of char in your query, so increase it to, say, 2000. Let me know if it solves your problem I will add as an answer.

Comment: thank you. it solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you defined a variable that holds `1000` chars and counting you string query in notepad++ I've noticed that the string contains `1770+` characters so SQL Server is truncating your string therefore trying to execute an incomplete query.

Change your variable to `@sqlKeyword nvarchar(2000)` and you should be fine.